# Worklight - Processing a received push notification in the background in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have tried the sample project for push notification both in android and iOS device and are working perfectly. Now I tried to edit the code. Instead of sending push thru the provided PushBackendEmulator, I created a button which will invoke the sending of push notification. I tried to invoke push notification through

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter: 'PushAdapter',
    procedure: 'submitNotification'
});
```

This is working fine in android. However, when I tried to run this in iOS, I was not able to received the actual push notification. But, the *pushNotificationReceived* function was triggered once I open the application. So, I want to receive the actual push notification even if the application is in the background. I have also set up apns successfully.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement. When the application is in the background - did you receive a notification in the device - in the notifications center or not?

Comment: Hi. I did not receive the notification in the notification center. But, when I opened my application, the pushNotificationReceived function was triggered.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario still. How can you both press a button in your application AND receive it when the app is in the background? To "send" you need to click the button in your app,  so the app needs to be in the foreground. Provide proper reproduction steps.

Comment: Ah. After clicking the button, I placed a timeout of 5 seconds before sending the notification. So I can click the button, send it to the background, then wait for the notification to arrive

Comment: What is the code for the timeout? Also, This is not proper behavior... you are not supposed to send push notifications from an application. Also, when an iOS app is put to the background it 'freezes' unless you specify certain abilities to keep the app running all the time -- also in the background.

Comment: I understand that this is not supposed to be the behavior. But, this is the client's request. This is my code for timeout: setTimeout(function, 5000); How do I specify the abilities to keep the app running in the background?

Comment: Ok. found it in this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/registering_applications_to_run_in_background/) thanks!

Comment: Hi, according to the [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/), I need to set the content-available to '1' in the json file for sending the push notification. I believe this is for native coding? Is there a way to set this since I am using hybrid?

Comment: Hmm if you are referring to background fetch then I believe Worklight does not support it...

Comment: so, there's no way to support this...?

Comment: see the following blog post regarding background fetch in iOS apps in Worklight: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ios_background_fetch?lang=en

Comment: Are you setting the timeout in the client or in the push adapter?  Are you sure that the adapter call in the client is completing before you put the app in the background?   Quick test - ignore the button in the client, put the app in the background, use work light studio to trigger your push adapter.  Do you get a notification in the notification center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process a received notification in iOS, while the application is in the background requires a new addition made available starting iOS7. This is termed "Background Fetch".

The following blog post by Nathan Hazout explains how to enable this feature in a Worklight-based iOS application: [Background Fetch in iOS 7 with Worklight](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ios_background_fetch?lang=en).

There is no short version for it, so I am not copying over any code bits; it is best to read it and follow through the provided steps.